# How to fix build errors from Qt header files (qchar.h and qbasicatomic.h) when building on mac?

Tags: c++, ios, qt

I'm trying to run a Qt project on mac and have an iOS build, however, it doesn't build due to "errors" in qt header files such qchar.h and qbasicatomic.h

Mac specs:
Qt Creator 4.5.0 (based on Qt Qt 5.10.0 Clang 7.0 64 bit)
macOS High Sierra (10.13.6)
Xcode (Version 9.4.1)

I've tried adding CONFIG+= c++11, bu that doesn't help.

[image: Click here to see the "errors" in the header qt files]

Here is the compile issue:

```
** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
    ProcessPCH SharedPrecompiledHeaders/precompile-egfdquqtyvgpwccxaewehzkwxdsd/precompile.h.pch ../trunk/precompile.h normal x86_64 c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
make: *** [xcodebuild-debug-simulator] Error 65
10:18:05: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project SerialSuite (kit: Qt 5.10.0 for iOS Simulator)
When executing step "Make"
```

Comment: I think many of your problems are caused by not having `c++11` enabled. Not sure why `CONFIG+= c++11` did not work. Did you run qmake after changing your `.pro`?

Comment: Unfortunately listing the errors isn't helpful. Can you please access the build log of QtCreator and add an example, failing, compiler command line to your question? I.e. so that can be seen what compiler flags were actually used to compile a module.

Comment: I'm guessing CONFIG += c++11 isn't working because it requires Qt 5.. but I can't upgrade due to the it making too many changes on the working code for windows

Comment: @Stefan Becker             ** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
 ProcessPCH SharedPrecompiledHeaders/precompile-egfdquqtyvgpwccxaewehzkwxdsd/precompile.h.pch ../trunk/precompile.h normal x86_64 c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
make: *** [xcodebuild-debug-simulator] Error 65
10:18:05: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project SerialProjectSuite (kit: Qt 5.10.0 for iOS Simulator)
When executing step "Make"

Comment: That doesn't look like a C++ compiler command line. Is that the *only* failing command in the log?

Comment: ***isn't working because it requires Qt 5*** You have `Qt-5.10`. Any Qt creator 4.X version should have supported `c++11`.

Comment: @drescherjm i added config += c++1... then cleaned, ran qmake and rebuilt and issue still persists.

Comment: It's trying to build your precompiled header as C instead of C++.